# Model update in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model like below.

```
var FolderModel = Backbone.SP.Item.extend({
    site: 'CapacityManagement',
    list: 'Folder',        
    parse: function(response) {
        var data = {};
        if (response.d) {                
            data.Id = response.d.Id;
            data.Active = response.d.Active;
            data.FolderName = response.d.FolderName;
            data.FolderTypeValue = response.d.FolderTypeValue;
            data.ParentFolderID = response.d.ParentFolderID;                
        }
        else {                
            data.Id = response.Id;
            data.Active = response.Active;
            data.FolderName = response.FolderName;
            data.FolderTypeValue = response.FolderTypeValue;
            data.ParentFolderID = response.ParentFolderID;                                
        }
        return data;
    }       
});
```

I am trying to update a model, but it is throwing an error in the parse function. The response variable is returning "undefined". But the code is working for creation and deletion.

This is how i am updating the value.

```
folder.save({'FolderName': data.FolderName}, {
            success: function (model,response,options) {},
            error: function (model, response, options) {}
        });
```

Comment: what is the error in parse function?

Comment: The response variable is set 'undefined' in the parse function

Comment: check the call if its successful and returning data in the response

Comment: my update is saving the result in the server, but its responding with 204 code. thats fine. but the problem is, its neither calling the success callback nor error callback. i am using the below library [link](https://github.com/lstak/Backbone.SharePoint/blob/master/backbone-sharepoint.odata.js)

Comment: 204 is not fine ...here's the problem... i think so ... you need to make it 200/201